# Quero mostrar o aniversariante 2 dias antes ou depois do evento?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho uma consulta que mostra no dashboard do sistema os aniversariantes da semana, todos que fazem aniversários entre domingo e sábado são exibidos na tela, porem fica muito chato ficar vendo até na sexta quem fez aniversario na segunda.
Teria a possibilidade de mudar a `query` que estou usando para mostrar o mesmo apenas 2 dias antes ou até 2 dias após?

**Minha Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE (WEEK(DATE_ADD(Aniversario, INTERVAL (YEAR(now()) - YEAR(Aniversario)) YEAR)) = WEEK(now()))
```

Fiz uma função em php mas ficou muito grande, então queria fazer na própria consulta sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Momesso, blz?

Veja no [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jYXALMaUQzEiBNgWmgNDK/0). Troque abaixo o `date '2019-01-05'` pelo `now()`.

```
select q.id, q.niver
from (select id, 
             date(concat(year(now()), '/', month(aniversario), '/', day(aniversario))) as niver
      from tbl_Usuarios) as q
where q.niver between date_add(date '2019-01-05', interval -2 day) and
                      date_add(date '2019-01-05', interval +2 day);
```

Comment: Fala Marcelao show.... Obrigado.